# Linux - grep a pattern with its value

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have large data file, like this:

```
AM_fep=1;AF=8.236e-06;AN=121412…
AM_fep =1; AN=121412;AF=0.000265…
AM_fep =2;AF=1.647e-05;AN=121412…
```

I require to grep only `AF=` field with its numeric value.
I have used `grep -o -E 'AF=[0-9]*'` but it gives the first digit of the value as:

```
AF=8
AF=0
AF=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires using grep's `-o` option which only prints the part of the line that matched the pattern.

We can match this with

```
grep -o 'AF=[^;]*' datafile
```

The pattern matches the literal string **AF=** followed by any number of non-semicolon characters.  Against your file, it produces

```
AF=8.236e-06
AF=0.000265…
AF=1.647e-05
```

Using `egrep` (or equivalently `grep -E`) we can require that there be at least one character after the equal sign with

```
egrep -o 'AF=[^;]+' datafile
```

---

The reason that your attempted pattern is not working is that it matches **AF=** followed by any number of digits.  Thus it can not pick up the decimal point (or the exponent symbol and negative sign).

Answer (score 1):

### An AWK Solution

Given your corpus, you can field-split on semicolons and then loop over each field on the line looking for `AF` as a match. For example:

```
$ awk -F\; '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /AF/) print $i}' /tmp/corpus 
AF=8.236e-06
AF=0.000265…
AF=1.647e-05
```

Note that the second example *correctly* matched the `…` ellipsis character contained in your posted corpus. Your real data probably doesn't have them, but if it does you can use the [match() or sub() string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) to exclude it. As an example:

```
$ awk -F\; '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /AF/) {sub(/…/, "", $i); print $i}}' \
  /tmp/corpus
AF=8.236e-06
AF=0.000265
AF=1.647e-05
```